# Pandas: selecting columns in a DataFrame question - e.g. row[1]['Column']

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I don't understand this line of code

```
minimum.append(min(j[1]['Data_Value']))
```

...specifically

```
j[1]['Data_Value']
```

I know the full code returns the minimum value and stores it in a list called minimum, but what does the **j[1]** do there? I've tried using other numbers to figure it out but get an error. Is it selecting the index or something?

Full code below. Thanks!

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib notebook

df1 = pd.read_csv('./data/C2A2_data/BinnedCsvs_d400/ed157460d30113a689e487b88dcbef1f5d64cbd8bb7825f5f485013d.csv')

minimum = []
maximum = []
month = []
df1 = df1[~(df1['Date'].str.endswith(r'02-29'))]
times1 = pd.DatetimeIndex(df1['Date'])


df = df1[times1.year != 2015]
times = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['Date'])
for j in df.groupby([times.month, times.day]):
    minimum.append(min(j[1]['Data_Value']))
    maximum.append(max(j[1]['Data_Value']))
```

Comment: What other numbers have you tried? It is the index. However it might be that there are only 2 columns. Then only 0 and 1 would work and you would get an error for other numbers ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Explanation**

pandas.groupby returns a list of tuples, (key, dataframe). Key is the groupby key; the key value of that group. See below for example.

Looping over these `j`'s, means looping over these tuples.

- j[0] refers to the group "key"
- j[1] means taking the dataframe component of that tuple. `['Data_Value']` takes a column of that dataframe.

**Example**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 1, 2], 'b': [2, 4, 6]})
df_grouped = df.groupby('a')

for j in df_grouped:
     print(f"Groupby key (col a): {j[0]}")
     print("dataframe:")
     print(j[1])
```

Yields:

```
Groupby key (col a): 1
dataframe:
   a  b
0  1  2
1  1  4
Groupby key (col a): 2
dataframe:
   a  b
2  2  6
```

**More readable solution**

Another, more comfortable, way to get the min/max of `Data_Value` for every month-day combination is this:

```
data_value_summary = df \
    .groupby([times.month, times.day]) \
    .agg({'Data_Value': [min, max]}) \
    ['Data_Value']  # < this removed the 2nd header from the newly created dataframe

minimum = data_value_summary['min']
maximum = data_value_summary['max']
```

Comment: Amazing! Much clearer explanation than the documentation